# How to emulate table cells with CSS (without float)?

Tags: css, html, inline

Got:

```
<ul>
    <li><div style="width:200px; display:table-cell;">Something here</div> <div style="width:40px; display:table-cell;">Edit</div> <div style="width:40px; display:table-cell;">Delete</div></li>
</ul>
```

Hopefull you get what I'm trying to do, have the first div be a fixed width. But I can't seem to do this, each div takes up a line by itself.

How can this be done without messy floats?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use HTML tables?

Comment: Why won't you want to use `float`? They aren't *that* messy, and with practice what you're doing can be whipped up very quickly.

Comment: I believe that to show tabular data, one must use HTML tables. CSS is the way to go for layouts but please, do not undermine tables to show tabular data. creating tables with css is as ugly as creating layouts with html tables.

Comment: Ok, I get it, just use a table ;)

Lists are nice though as I want to have a second level list thats indented a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, never do that again! The way to do it would be *with* floats, but you really **NEVER** wanna use something like that! By the way, `div`'s aren't allowed within an `ul`. If you wanna display data like that, you should use real tables.

Did I mention that you really shouldn't use that under any circumstance?

Comment: It's probably not tabular data he's trying to display, so it would not be appropriate to use a table.  If support for the table display properties was better, I also wouldn't suggest that floats are necessarily better.

Comment: Floats make it difficult to handle wrapping data.

Answer (score 1):

> Hopefull you get what I'm trying to do, have the first div be a fixed width. But I can't seem to do this, each div takes up a line by itself.

For `display-table:cell` to have effect, the parent element needs to be set to `display: table-row` and the parent parent element to `display: table`.

That said: Are you sure a `<table>` element is not the more appropriate thing here?

Comment: Why would a `table` be more appropriate here? It may be slightly easier to layout, but isn't it obvious that this *isn't* tabular data?

Comment: @Yi how do you deduct that this is not tabular data?

Comment: The two other 'cells' contain actions 'delete' and 'edit'. There is no data with which he is attempting to correlate the data in the first cell with - instead what he is attempting to create is most likely something like a control/management panel for contents, like blog posts.

Comment: @Yi and a control/management panel for blog posts is not tabular data? I'm not following you. Also, I am not saying it *is* tabular data; I am merely asking the OP to think whether he is using the correct tag.

Comment: No its not - there is no *data*, but rather a list of actions. On both semantics and practicality I'd say that the structure should be a `ul` of action with a `p class="preview"` sibling and a `li class="blog-post"` parent. Also, if you're not saying that it is tabular data then why suggest `table` as more appropriate? On an entirely separate note, can you stop referring to me as 'Yi' - its not polite. I know its a cultural thing, but *Yi Jiang* is my last name. 'Yi' doesn't mean anything. Sorry if I sound rude.

Comment: @Yi Jiang whether this is tabular data or not is really a pointless discussion. I am showing the OP how to make his current method work, and suggesting that he think about whether he's using the correct tag, nothing more. If you want to discuss whether this is tabular data, why not take it to @GuidoH who is certain it is. As to the addressing - I'm happy to use your full name, no problem.

Comment: Thanks Pekka and Yi, so far it looks like there is no CSS solution without using floats (which I believe are messy due to needing clear styles)

Comment: @Pekka yeah I did, but that needs parent elements to have styles attached. I'm just shocked at how difficult it is to create inline fixed width blocks using CSS (without messy floats)

Answer (score 0):

Use span instead of div perhaps? (avoid new lines)

Comment: Thanks but couldnt get span to work. Tried display:inline-block; but didnt work either